# How to get current input value in a div list with javascript button?

Tags: javascript

I spent many time and I read a lot of articles here, but unfortunately I am still in trouble.

In the following code, how can I assign the correct input value to correct button?

My trials below return "always first input" or "undefined".

Many thanks,

Murat

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("test2").onclick = function() {searchin()};
            function searchin() {
            // I tried every row below independently, not all of them at once (with or w/o "var" at the beginning):
                metin2 = $(this).parent().find('input[name="metin2"]').val();
                metin2 = $('input[name="metin2"]').val();
                var metin2 = $(this).closest('.results').attr('data-artnr');
                var metin2 = $(this).closest('.results').find('input[name="metin2"]').val();
            // I tried every row above independently, not all of them at once:
            alert(metin2);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="results" data-artnr="1111">
           <input type="text" class="test1" name="metin2" value="1111"><br><br>
           <input type="button" class="test2" value="Suche (Basic)" onclick="searchin()"><br><br>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="results" data-artnr="2222">
           <input type="text" class="test1" name="metin2" value="2222"><br><br>
           <input type="button" class="test2" value="Suche (Basic)" onclick="searchin()"><br><br>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="results" data-artnr="3333">
           <input type="text" class="test1" name="metin2" value="3333"><br><br>
           <input type="button" class="test2" value="Suche (Basic)" onclick="searchin()"><br><br>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstly you try to access test2 before it exists, secondly this is a very weird construct `document.getElementById("test2").onclick = function() {searchin()};` thirdly you load jQuery, so why not use it? Also don't use inline event handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You try to access test2 before it exists
- You load jQuery, so why not use it? 
  This is not jQuery `document.getElementById("test2").onclick = function() {searchin()};` whereas this is: `$(".test2").on("click", function() {`
- Don't use inline event handling (onclick="searchin()") and for sure not at the same time as assigning event handlers in script

All your selectors work when the wrapping code works

I would personally use `$(this).prevAll("input").val()`

Here is the preferred and recommended method to assign event handlers using jQuery

```js
$(function() { // when page loads
  $(".test2").on("click", function() { // click any class="test2"
    var metin2a = $(this).parent().find('input[name="metin2"]').val();
    var metin2b = $('input[name="metin2"]').val();
    var metin2c = $(this).closest('.results').attr('data-artnr');
    var metin2d = $(this).closest('.results').find('input[name="metin2"]').val();

    var metin2e = $(this).prevAll("input").val(); // my preference
    var metin2f = $(this).prevAll(".test1").val(); // or this

    console.log("a",metin2a,"b",metin2b,"c",metin2c,"d",metin2d,"e",metin2e,"f",metin2f);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results" data-artnr="1111">
  <input type="text" class="test1" name="metin2" value="1111"><br><br>
  <input type="button" class="test2" value="Suche (Basic)" ><br><br>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="results" data-artnr="2222">
  <input type="text" class="test1" name="metin2" value="2222"><br><br>
  <input type="button" class="test2" value="Suche (Basic)" ><br><br>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="results" data-artnr="3333">
  <input type="text" class="test1" name="metin2" value="3333"><br><br>
  <input type="button" class="test2" value="Suche (Basic)" ><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks @mplungjan, It works. I will apply it to my entire code. Sorry for weird things in my post, I am very new to javascript :) Btw, you say "You load jQuery, so why not use it?", how to do that? Has it been already applied to your solution snippet? and you say "Don't use inline event handling", can you explain a bit more? many thanks again...

Comment: thank you @mplungjan . Is `$(function() {...}` part still in the `<head>` ?

Comment: @Murat The beauty of `$(function() {....});` is that  it can now be anywhere  - I would put it in the head

Comment: PS: Only one of the var assignments of metin2 is necessary  - for example the one called metin2e or metin2f

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` is also in the `<head>` ?

Comment: Yes anywhere before the script that  assigns the handlers. JQuery must be present before the first $(...)

Answer (score 0):

When function called from `onclick` attribute `onclick="searchin()"` inside her hot defined variable `this`. Therefore all methods with this variable returning `undefined`.

You must pass this variable explicit like `onclick="searchin.apply(this)"` or assign onClick event handler with jQuery

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.test2').click(function() {
    var metin2 = $(this).parent().find('input[name="metin2"]').val();
    console.log('Parent.Find: ' + metin2);
    metin2 = $('input[name="metin2"]').val();
    console.log('Global: ' + metin2);
    metin2 = $(this).closest('.results').attr('data-artnr');
    console.log('data-artnr: ' + metin2);
    var metin2 = $(this).closest('.results').find('input[name="metin2"]').val();
    console.log('Closest.Find: ' + metin2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results" data-artnr="1111">
  <input type="text" class="test1" name="metin2" value="1111"><br><br>
  <input type="button" class="test2" value="Suche (Basic)"><br><br>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="results" data-artnr="2222">
  <input type="text" class="test1" name="metin2" value="2222"><br><br>
  <input type="button" class="test2" value="Suche (Basic)"><br><br>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="results" data-artnr="3333">
  <input type="text" class="test1" name="metin2" value="3333"><br><br>
  <input type="button" class="test2" value="Suche (Basic)"><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe I already answered this in full - no need to use apply in the inline handler. The biggest error was setting the handler before the field exists

Comment: Hi Anton Shchyrov, many thanks for your help too, It is also working. Both your answer and @mplungjan 's answer work. Which approach is better? My question is for both of you.

Comment: @Murat - using unobtrusive event handlers is the preferred and recommended way. The code I posted uses that

Comment: @Murat It is better to separate markup and code and assign all event handlers from JS code.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing jQuery in the project. Make the most out of it.
write a jQuery click handler and access '$(this)' element and find the input inside the parent. I highly suggest using a button instead of an input element.
Check this codepen for the complete solution.

```
// Button click event handler
  $(".test2").click(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().find(".test1").val()); 
  });
```

https://codepen.io/bharathravi27/pen/pxgZBG

Comment: Please use the snippet editor here  - the button in the editor looks like a document with tags `[<>]` - that said, did you read my answer at all?

Comment: Thanks, I haven't. I was writing codepen and posted it. Now seeing you answer here. Same thought here

Comment: Hi @Bharath . Many thanks for your interest. I think your approach is also same as mplungjan's and Anton Shchyrov's ones. It is okay now.